# What is the difference between these two tab-delimited .txt files that is causing .split("\t") to properly separate values from one but not the other?

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, csv

I have two Japanese word frequency reports that were compiled from different sources. Each line contains a word and its number of occurrences, delimited by tabs. I also have a python script that is supposed to split each line into those two values using `.split("\t")`. The latter value is then converted into an integer, which is where the error is coming from:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\ufeff29785713'
```

This is only occurring for data from the second file.

Upon testing to see if converting the number to a float would work (or change the error), the result was this:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\ufeff29785713'
```

Is this a result of the tabs or numerals in the second file perhaps not technically being the same character and not delimiting properly, causing unwanted characters in the latter value (or perhaps not splitting at all)? Both files are UTF-8 encoded.

[Shorter version of first file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qop1O5hFqGsZl3p-GDLgqxk2h6kaogr0/view?usp=sharing) (working)

[Shorter version of second file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13rWIqJgdmAcI_VhY3Gz1bDoA4doJEKpY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The second file appears to have a byte order mark FEFF in the middle of the stream (after every tab). This doesn't really make sense

Comment: How could I go about clearing it from the file?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `split`. `split` works perfectly fine, but after splitting by `\t`, there's an extra `"\uffef"` at the start of the string you're trying to convert to int. The Unicode character `U+FEFF` is the byte order mark that is used to tell the difference between big- and little-endian encoding.

Comment: I have found the solution. I managed to clear the string of the tag using ```.replace(u'\ufeff','')```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, not a python dev at all, but given that your second array element contains a rogue character pair you could try removing it after you split and before you convert to number:

```
x[1] = x[1].replace('\ufeff', '')
```

`x` being the name of the array you did split your line into. The replace operation will have no effect on the first file, because FEFF is not present